# ipad youtube embed, blocks touches on lower z-index

Tags: youtube-api, mobile-safari, youtube-javascript-api, html5-video

On iPad I've been experiencing an issue where lower z-index items can not receive touch events.

The cause of that there is a `<video>` tag within the iframe which blocks interaction with lower z-index elements. All my usual fixes for ipad force-redraw has messed up the embed in some way. Either :

- the video either plays audio only
- or the entire iframe is not clickable.

#### Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krismeister/KynXG/3/

Setting `'controls':0` will fix this issue, but there is no JS interface to re-activate the controls, once the video has started.

### edit:

I found [this issue in the yt-data](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ipad&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=4569) bug tracker. Please vote it up.

Comment: The underlying bug has been resolved.